# How to check if two nodes are connected with recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, pass-by-reference

In an interview I have recently been asked a similar question as the below: I had to build a recursive function that shows whether two Nodes are connected. how can I make the below code work? Is there a way to pass a,b,c 'by reference' so when they become instantiated this is effective when I call check_connection. Node is a mutable object, so it should act as if it was by reference, but this doesn't seem to be the case, as there is an error: 'NoneType is not iterable'. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, neighbours):
        self.neighbours=neighbours

    def return_neighbours(self):
        return self.neighbours

def check_connection(first, second):
    connections=first.return_neighbours()
    for conection in connections:
        if second in conection:
            return True
        else:
            check_connection(conection,second)

a=None
b=None
c=None

a=Node(neighbours=[c])
b=Node(neighbours=[c])
c=Node(neighbours=[a,b])

check_connection(a,c)
```

Comment: When you recursively call `check_connection` in the `else:` block, you're not _returning_ its value; you're just calling it and then throwing the returned value away, which means the function has no `return` statement at all, meaning it returns `None` by default.

Comment: It's a recursive function so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: It's unclear how `check_connection` is supposed to announce its results.  It returns `True` if the second node is in the neighbours list, so this suggests that it is intended to always return `True` or `False`.  However it returns nothing at all (hence `None`) if the second node is not in the neighbours list, and when it is called at the bottom of the script the return value is not even captured, so that suggests you intended some other way for the function to announce its result (perhaps a `print` statement that you left out?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that None is not a mutable object. Rather than setting a,b,c to None, you should have set them to Nodes with no neighbors. That way they would be changed by the declarations that followed. As you currently have it neighbors of a is not c but rather None, because c was just a variable pointing to None at that point, not a reference to a Node object.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.neighbours=None

def check_connection(first, second):
    if second in first.neighbours:
        print ("Connection found")
        exit()
    else:
        for conection in first.neighbours:
            check_connection(conection,second)

a=Node()
b=Node()
c=Node()

a.neighbours=[c]
b.neighbours=[c]
c.neighbours=[a,b]

check_connection(a,c)
```